# All the time null value when using find method

Tags: laravel

I'm getting null value when using `find` where method

```
$user = Auth::user();
$userId = intval($user->id);

$userType = Usertype::find($userId);
```

`$userType` is null even I have updated `protected $primaryKey = 'id';` in my model.
Could you please suggest why I'm getting `null` value

if I use `$userType = Usertype::find('55');`, it works fine

Comment: Have you checked $userId value? i think that you are trying to get a user who isn't exist in your database.

Comment: why did you use quotes in `find()` method? shouldn't it be integer?

Comment: How are `User` and `Usertype` models related?  If you have a User with `id` 55, how do you know there is a Usertype with id 55 too?

Comment: Because when I hit to print userType it return the user id 55 It has the value. Does any relation need between user and usertype?

Comment: Also I dont knw is there a problem I'm using auto default login laravel functionality.